# Adding markers to Google Maps only when needed

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am able to display a Google Maps map on a web site and load hundreds of markers for the current map area and display them. The problem is how to behave when the map is zoomed in/out or is moved, so the map area changes.

There is a part of the map that is the same than before, and so are the markers in it. But there is a part of the map that is new and new markers should be added.

Right now I am doing the simplest solution, clearing all markers, retrieving markers for the current map area and add them. This produces a flickery effect on the markers (obviously) due to clear and add immediately after.

What is a efficient way to deal with this situation?

Is there a way to check if a marker has already been added to the map?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a marker cluster or a clustering algorithm to group marker that are close together when you zoom out and ungroup them when you zoom in. It can significantly reduce the database query time and the map drawing. A good solution is a kd-tree.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a marker has been added to the map, call the getMap method of the marker and if it returns a map object, it has been added.

To check if a marker is in the visible area of the map, you can call the getBounds method on the map which returns a LatLngBounds. Then call the contains method of the returned LatLngBounds passing the coordinates of the marker.

Hope this helps